# How to iterate over a map in mvel

Tags: java, mvel

I have a collection (map) which I want to use with the foreach orb tag.

How do i do this in mvel and is it also possible to get the current key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

//java
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}

//mvel
foreach (c : map.entrySet) 
{

   System.out.println("Key = " +c.key + ", Value = " +c.value);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c.key` and `c.value` in the mval expression?

Comment: I tried that and I get an exception  org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntimeError: cannot iterate object type: java.util.HashMap

Comment: @FaroukAlhassan try this: `foreach (c : map.entrySet)`

Comment: Thanks. That threw exception : cannot access entrySet, so i changed it to entrySet() but now its throwing NPE...ALthough I'm 100% sure the map is not null...

Comment: Is that due to the version of mvel I'm using? 2.0.19

Comment: map.entrySet gave error. but map.entrySet() worked. thx a lot